# Find the highest set bit

Tags: php, math, bitwise-operators, bit

I have 5 different values which are saved as bits like 10010.
I get the value as an Int from the Database (cannot change that) so like 24 means 11000
I know that i can get the biggest bit here by using

```
if ((decbin($d) & 16) == 16)
```

but if the first is 0 i would have to check the next bit, and if that is 0 i would have to ...

So after all i would have a block of ifs and if there were more bits the block was bigger.
Is there a simple way to just get the "id" (or value, would not matter) of the highest bit with a 1?

Comment: Moreover, I don't know if your code would work, as looking in the PHP manual I see that decbin returns a string.. To do what you intended to do, you simply needed to do if(($d & 16) == 16) etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Compute the base 2 logarithm of the number and `floor` it:

```
$highbit = floor(log($d, 2));
```

If `$highbit`, for instance, is 5, it means that the 5th bit is the highest bit set to 1.

Comment: This is cool, but be sure to note that $highbit is the bit index, not a 1-based bit position.

Answer (score 1):

The highest bit set in an integer is equal to the integer base-2 logarithm of that integer.

While there exist many different implementations for doing that kind of thing in assembler and C and such, more or less efficiently, the probably easiest way to do it in PHP is to actually use logarithm.

The log() function surely is not the most efficient way of solving the problem, but seeing as you are in a script language, it probably won't be any slower (and quite possibly faster) than implementing one of the "better" algorithms in PHP with 2 dozen statements.

Thus:

$highestbit = (int)(log($value,2));

Answer (score 0):

Interesting ... had to check for rounding-problems immediately and found none in the range of up to 1'000'000, though my test-code revealed problems for less native bases, like 3:

3^5 = 243 but floor(log(243, 3)) gives 4

Answer (score -1):

```
def hibit(v):
    """ uint v -> highest bit: 0101 -> 0100, 01xxxx -> 010000 """
    # cf http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html
    v |= v >> 1
    v |= v >> 2
    v |= v >> 4
    v |= v >> 8
    v |= v >> 16
    return v ^ (v >> 1)

for v in range(0, 9+1) + range(2**31-1, 2**31+2):
    print v, hibit(v)
```

Comment: That's the wrong language. As the question was asking for the index of the bit, not an int with only the highest bit set.